# Create a class which contains an array of instances from another class

Tags: javascript

I have a class "Dot"

```
  let Dot= function (x, y, z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}
```

And I want to create another class "Poly" which contains a bunch of instances of class Dot like this:

```
class Poly {

    constructor(nDots){
        for(let i = 0; i < nDots; i++){
            this.dots[i] = new Dot(Math.floor(Math.random() * 600), Math.floor(Math.random() * 600), Math.floor(Math.random() * 600));
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't think it's possible to use FOR loop in a constructor. :) 
Any solution for my problem?
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: `I don't think it's possible to use FOR loop in a constructor` Why not? What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use `for` loops in a constructor. Your problem is that you didn't initialize `this.dots` array:

```
constructor(nDots) {
    this.dots = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < nDots; i++){
        this.dots[i] = /* ... */;
    }
}
```

BTW, it's better to use `Array#push` to fill the array instead of `[i]`:

```
this.dots.push( /* ... */ );
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast feedback. You're right! But now the constructor create an empty array. It's a scope problem? How can I solve it ?

Comment: @dem.1797 What scope problem? Did you replace the `/* ... */` part with `new Dot(...)`?

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `this.dots[i]` and now it should work.

Also for [array manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) in this specific case you can use array.push(...).